# Pasar el texto de un Button de un Activity a otro Activity

Tags: java, android

Antes de nada perdonar mi ignorancia, llevo 2 días aprendiendo a programar para Android y ando algo perdido.

Como dice el título intento pasar el texto de un botón de un activity a otro

El codigo del primer activity:

```
private Button btnBorrachos;
private Button btnAnimales;

private String sendBundle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnBorrachos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBorrachos);
    btnAnimales = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnimales);


    btnBorrachos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            sendBundle = btnBorrachos.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PruebaActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("txtbundle", sendBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnAnimales.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendBundle = btnAnimales.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnimalesActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("txtbundle", sendBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Lo que intento hacer es que dependiendo del botón que se de, capture el texto de ese botón en la variable sendBundle y con Intent mandarlo luego al segundo activity.

Código del segundo activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prueba);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    switch (bundle.getString("txtbundle")) {
        case "Borrachos":
            Toast.makeText(PruebaActivity.this, "Ha llegado 'Borrachos'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            break;
        case "Animales":
            Toast.makeText(PruebaActivity.this, "Ha llegado 'Animales'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(PruebaActivity.this, "Ha llegado DESCONOCIDO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

}
```

Supuestamente lo que debería hacer es que dependiendo del texto que le llega de cada botón muestro un Toast u otro. Pero no muestra ninguno en ningún caso.

la comparación parece que está bien, estos son los textos de los botones:

```
android:text="Borrachos"
android:text="Animales"
```

Comment: Buenos dias @Rodrypaladin, perdona la pregunta no estarias viendo solamente el Toast?, esto se deberia porque le falta agregar el .show() a tu metodo para presentarlos, algo como esto `Toast.makeText(PruebaActivity.this, "Ha llegado 'Borrachos'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: Gracias, menudo error más tonto, llevaba un largo tiempo y no era capaz de verlo

Answer (score 0):

Como han dicho en los comentarios te falta el .show en los Toast, pero yo además para el uso que le quieres dar implementaría el View.OnClickListener directamente en la Activity, y luego pillaría en el evento el bottón que ha sido, además te quitas la necesidad de las variables globales.

```
public class MainActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button myButton;
        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBorrachos);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnimales);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String sendBundle = ((Button)v).getText().toString();       
        Intent intent;
        switch(sendBundle){
            case "Animales":
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnimalesActivity.class);
                break;
            case "Borrachos":
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PruebaActivity.class);
                break;
        }
        intent.putExtra("txtbundle", sendBundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```